# How are CMB frame redshifts of galaxies corrected for coherent flows?

Tags: cosmology, redshift, velocity, cosmic-microwave-background

Say, if I downloaded the CMB frame redshifts of some galaxies from [NED](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/) database, then what is the procedure to correct it for coherent flows?

I'm using the [SNooPy](https://csp.obs.carnegiescience.edu/data/snpy)(snpy) Python package to analyze some Type Ia supernova data collected from [CSP](https://csp.obs.carnegiescience.edu/data/CSP_Photometry_DR3.tgz/view) archive. snpy provides a method called [sn.get_zcmb()](https://users.obs.carnegiescience.edu/cburns/SNooPyDocs/html/snpy.html?highlight=get_zcmb#snpy.sn.sn.get_zcmb) to collect the redshift of the SNe Ia host galaxy corrected to CMB frame from NED calculator. Now, for cosmological studies mere z_cmb isn't enough, we need to correct it for bulk coherent flow as per literature. But the procedure to correct for it isn't known to me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: CMB frame redshifts are already corrected for large-scale flows; that’s why they have that name.